# How can i connect to socks proxy (in browser or in Frontend) with javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, socks

I need to connect to host server with socks that have username and password (no http or http-proxy) just with socks protocol.
My frameworks that I have used is NodeJs, AangularJs, and ElectornJs.

### I tested 3 methods , but can't connect to the server.

My program writes with angular and electron, how can use socks in Nodejs? how can send Http request in Angular and Electron through this socks?

Comment: I would think how a browser connects to the internet is up to the end user - doubt you can change that in a webpage using javascript - I can see how that could be abused by the wrong people

Comment: You did not provide enough information, may be this can help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/socks

Comment: My program write with angular and electron , how can use socks in Nodejs ? how can send send Http request in Angular and Electron through this socks ?